# Can't use prev item and next item link on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to cycle through two items the the prev item and next item options. It works initially, but when I cycle to the next item, I can't go back to the previous. Any idea why?

HTML

```
<section class="st" id="item1">
Item 1<p>
    <a id="prevItem" href="#">Previous Item</a>
    <a id="nextItem" href="#">Next Item</a>
</section>

<section class="st" id="item2">
Item 2
    <p>
    <a id="prevItem" href="#">Previous Item</a>
    <a id="nextItem" href="#">Next Item</a>
</section>
```

JS

```
$("#item2").hide()
$("#nextItem").click(function(){        
    if($('#item1').is(':visible')) {
        $("#item1").hide();
        $("#item2").show();
    }
    else if($('#item2').is(':visible')) {
        $("#item1").show();
        $("#item2").hide();
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/by0bze5e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two elements with the same `id` and expect it to work.  Change them to classes and it will most likely work fine.

```
<a class="prevItem" href="#">Previous Item</a>
<a class="nextItem" href="#">Next Item</a>

$("#item2").hide()
$(".nextItem").click(function(){        
    $("#item1, #item2").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/by0bze5e/2/

Answer (score 2):

You must have unique IDs on a HTML page for it to be valid. Use classes instead to match the buttons:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/by0bze5e/4/

```
$("#item2").hide()
$(".prevItem").click(function(){        
    if($('#item1').is(':visible')) {
        $("#item1").hide();
        $("#item2").show();
    }
    else if($('#item2').is(':visible')) {
        $("#item1").show();
        $("#item2").hide();
    }
});
```